# How do I use regex to match strings that don't contain certain substrings?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match javascript libraries that haven't been minified yet.  I've got the data and my current regex http://www.regexr.com/3b569 but you can see I'm matching the last library (`angularytics.min.js`) which I don't want to match.

I'm just not quite sure how to negate the optional possibility of `'.min.js'` in my matches.

Comment: Take a look at [RexEgg: Lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) and read up on Negative Lookahead.

Comment: Thanks @hwnd, it looks like I would ideally like something like a negative lookbehind.  Unfortunately it's not supported in javascript.  I'll keep reading about the Negative Lookahead.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you...I need to process what's going on there so I can come to those solutions on my own.  I appreciate you pointing me to a good resource.  I'll choose this as an answer if you put it in as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement Negative Lookahead here:

```
bower_components(?!.*min\.js).*\.js
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways you can do:

```
/(?!.*\.min\.js$)bower_components.*\.js/gm
```

See [DEMO](http://www.regexr.com/3b56i)

Comment: Thank you, that definitely does it.  I"m wondering if there's some way to include the .min negation in the regex closer to where one might expect to find it in the original string?

Comment: @hwnd provided `bower_components(?!.*min).*\.js` and it's exactly the kind of thing I was hoping for.  Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably narrow it down further, so that not just any `min` fails
the regex.
*edit* - Add a lazy quantifier to find the first `.js` if there is more than 1.
You could also qualify the `.js` that it is at/near the end by adding `(?=[^\S\r\n]*(?:\r?\n|$))`

`bower_components(?:(?!min\.js).)*?\.js`

```
 bower_components
 (?:
      (?! min\.js )
      . 
 )*?
 \.js
```

Comment: @hwnd provided `bower_components(?!.*min).*\.js` and it's exactly the kind of thing I was hoping for.  Thanks for answering!